# Errors during currency conversion on multiple line transaction

Tags: c#, transactions, currency, accounting

I have a problem that I think may not have an answer other then completely rethinking the application, but hopefully you guys can prove me wrong!

I have an application that uses an Exchange Rate to back calculate a Base value from a Currency value to four decimal places.  The calculation is pretty simple, and passes all the relevant unit tests giving correct results each time:

```
    public static decimal GetBaseValue(decimal currencyAmount, RateOperator rateOperator, 
        double exchangeRate)
    {
        if (exchangeRate <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ErrorType.
               ExchangeRateLessThanOrEqualToZero.ErrorInfo().Description);
        }

        decimal baseValue = 0;

        if (currencyAmount != 0)
        {
            switch (rateOperator)
            {
                case RateOperator.Divide:
                    baseValue = Math.Round(currencyAmount * Convert.ToDecimal(exchangeRate), 
                        4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    break;
                case RateOperator.Multiply:
                    baseValue = Math.Round(currencyAmount / Convert.ToDecimal(exchangeRate), 
                        4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rateOperator));
            }
        }

        return baseValue;
    }
```

I also have the equivalent to calculate currency from base, not shown to avoid confusing the issue and in any case pretty much identical code apart from parameter names and the reversal of the math operators in the switch statement.

My problem comes when I need to apply this process to a transaction which has multiple lines.  The rule is that the total of the debits must equal the total of the credits, but some numbers are out by a fraction of a penny.  This is because we are totalling the result of two or more individually converted numbers against a single conversion, and I believe that the accumulated rounding causes the error.

Let us assume the following:

1. Item value of $1.00
2. VAT value of $0.20 (20%)
3. Exchange rate of 1.4540 dollars to the pound

Now let us review an example transaction:

```
Line #  Debit    Credit
1                $1.20
2       $1.00
3       $0.20
```

This passes the test, as total credits match total debits.

When we convert (divide each dollar value by 1.454), we see the problem:

```
Line #  Debit    Credit
1                £0.8253
2       £0.6878
3       £0.1376
========================
Total   £0.8254  £0.8253 
========================
```

This fails and breaks the rule, I believe as a result of the two sets of rounding in the debit column and only one set on the credit column. Yet, I need to be able to calculate backwards and forwards with accuracy, and I need to make sure that the transaction balances in Currency and in Base across all the lines.

So to my question: how best to address this problem? Anyone experienced something similar, and if so do you mind sharing how you resolved it?

**EDIT - The Solution I Used**

Following the answer from Charles that pointed me absolutely in the right direction I am posting my working method for the benefit of anyone else who might face a similar issue.  Whilst understanding that this specific code may not be suitable for a direct copy and paste solution, I hope that the comments and the procedure followed will be of help:

```
    private static void SetBaseValues(Transaction transaction)
    {
        // Get the initial currency totals
        decimal currencyDebitRunningTotal = transaction.CurrencyDebitTotal;
        decimal currencyCreditRunningTotal = transaction.CurrencyCreditTotal;

        // Only one conversion, but we do one per column
        // Note that the values should be the same anyway 
        // or the transaction would be invalid
        decimal baseDebitRunningTotal = 
            Functions.GetBaseValue(currencyDebitRunningTotal, 
            transaction.MasterLine.RateOperator, 
            transaction.MasterLine.ExchangeRate);
        decimal baseCreditRunningTotal = 
            Functions.GetBaseValue(currencyCreditRunningTotal,
            transaction.MasterLine.RateOperator, 
            transaction.MasterLine.ExchangeRate);

        // Create a list of transaction lines that belong to this transaction
        List<TransactionLineBase> list = new List<TransactionLineBase> 
        { transaction.MasterLine };
        list.AddRange(transaction.TransactionLines);

        // If there is no tax line, don't add a null entry 
        // as that would cause conversion failure
        if (transaction.TaxLine != null)
        {
            list.Add(transaction.TaxLine);
        }

        // Sort the list ascending by value
        var workingList = list.OrderBy(
            x => x.CurrencyCreditAmount ?? 0 + x.CurrencyDebitAmount ?? 0).ToList();

        // Iterate the lines excluding any entries where Credit and Debit 
        // values are both null (this is possible on some rows on 
        // some transactions types e.g. Reconciliations
        foreach (var line in workingList.Where(
            line => line.CurrencyCreditAmount != null || 
            line.CurrencyDebitAmount != null))
        {
            if (transaction.CanConvertCurrency)
            {
                SetBaseValues(line);
            }
            else
            {
                var isDebitLine = line.CurrencyCreditAmount == null;

                if (isDebitLine)
                {
                    if (line.CurrencyDebitAmount != 0)
                    {
                        line.BaseDebitAmount = 
                            line.CurrencyDebitAmount ?? 0 / 
                            currencyDebitRunningTotal * baseDebitRunningTotal;
                        currencyDebitRunningTotal -= 
                            line.CurrencyDebitAmount ?? 0;
                        baseDebitRunningTotal -= line.BaseDebitAmount ?? 0;                            
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line.CurrencyCreditAmount != 0)
                    {
                        line.BaseCreditAmount = 
                            line.CurrencyCreditAmount ?? 0/
                       currencyCreditRunningTotal*baseCreditRunningTotal;
                        currencyCreditRunningTotal -= line.CurrencyCreditAmount ?? 0;
                        baseCreditRunningTotal -= line.BaseCreditAmount ?? 0;
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does rather depend on the situation, but one option for this is to only convert the totals and then allocate this proportionately to each of the parts using a reducing balance method.  This ensures that the sum of the parts will always equal the total exactly.

Your debit and credit columns both add up to $1.20, so you convert this at your rate giving you £0.8253.

You then proportionately allocate this to your debit amounts from the smallest up to the largest.  The theory behind the sorting is that you're less likely to care about the extra/missing pennies of a larger number.

So you start with the totals of $1.20 and £0.6878 and then calculate the proportion of your converted balance that applies to your smallest dollar amount:

```
$0.20 / $1.20 * 0.8253 = £0.1376
```

You then deduct the amounts from your totals (this is the 'reducing balance' part):

```
$1.20 - $0.20 = $1.00
£0.8253 - £0.1376 = £0.6877
```

And then calculate the next largest (as you only have 1 more amount in this example, this is trivial):

```
$1.00 / $1.00 * £0.6877 = £0.6877
```

So this gives you:

```
Line #  Debit    Credit
1                £0.8253
2       £0.6877
3       £0.1376
========================
Total   £0.8253  £0.8253 
========================
```

Comment: Hi Charles,

Thank you for your intriguing post.  The theory makes sense, but would not be accurately reversible and would not fit in with the current processing method that basically works through the lines in order.  That is not to say that it could not be accomplished, but it would mean a complete change to the system.  I will think on it some more and discuss with the powers that be to see if this is a potential way forward.  I will post as soon as I have any form of decision.  Thanks again for taking the time and effort to answer.

Comment: @oldcoder no problem. As you've worked out (and as Peter pointed out), the only way to do this is to only convert one number and calculate the others based on that - either using his suggestion using specific domain knowledge like the VAT rate, or by using this more generic method.  If you convert each without context, the cumulative rounding errors will cause small discrepancies.

Comment: Hi Charles,

Your answer led me to the correct solution.  It did involve a little re-engineering  to allow it to work with existing code, and to cover all possibilities took quite a lot of effort and error trapping but the result is working perfectly and all related unit and integration tests passing  100%.  One particular thing of note was that I had to run Credit and Debit running totals for both Currency and Base values in order to make sure that all the necessary values were available. 

Thank you for your help which is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a business problem not a programming one. The results you're seeing are a result of mathematical rounding. In financial calculations the business will decide when the exchange rate is applied and it has to be applied once. For example, in your case it might be decided to apply it to the item value and then multiply by the VAT to get your total. This is also typically  present in your regions accepted accounting/financial accepted  standards.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately the application works (or rather should work) with any currency anywhere in the world, and the rules that i have to adhere to are stated in the question.  I cannot see how this problem can be solved because the individual lines still have to be calculated and the base and currency values available for further utilisation.

Changing the rules might work if we can still apply GAAP, but what changes?  Rounding to 2 places could work, but technically breaks the rules and I have not run sufficient tests to be certain it would always work...

Comment: You're questions encapsulate the challenges with working on currency exchange . In my answer, it wouldn't matter what currency you used if you only apply the exchange once you'll always be able to convert to and from the base currency with precision. Rounding to the least precise number (meaning two decimals in your case) won't work either. Like I said, it's a mathematical impossibility to accomplish with consistent results if you apply the exchange at multiple places in your calculations. Sorry if it seems I'm being insistent, I've had this problem before working with financial apps.

Comment: Hi Peter4499,

Yes, I said in my question that I was pretty sure that it was not practical mathematically.  Calculating it only once is not possible, because each line has to have a base value and there could be any number of lines in a transaction - I provided a demonstrative but simple example of the problem. That leaves me with three possibilities - change the system, change the rules, or ignore the tiny little error.  I am not sure if I can actually do any of those, but thanks for the input anyway which is appreciated.